# How do I filter data based on specific character from specific field in Unix?

Tags: unix

EmpID:Name:Designation:UnitName:Location:DateofJoining:Salary

1001:Thomson:SE:IVS:Mumbai:10-Feb-1999:60000

1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000

1003:Jackson:DM:IMS:Hyderabad:23-Apr-1985:90000

1004:BobGL::ETA:Mumbai:05-Jan-2004:55000

1005:Alice:PA:::26-Aug-2014:25000

1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000

1007:Kirsten:PM:IMS:Mumbai:26-Aug-2014:45000

1004:BobGL::ETA:Mumbai:05-Jan-2021:55000

Display the Employee details of all those working in a location that has 'a' in its location name.

I tried this  grep "`cut -d ":" -f5 employee.txt | grep '*a*'`" employee.txt  but it isn't working.

Comment: What is the output you see? Also I think you need a space between `-f` and 5.

Comment: 1001:Thomson:SE:IVS:Mumbai:10-Feb-1999:60000
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1003:Jackson:DM:IMS:Hyderabad:23-Apr-1985:90000
1004:BobGL::ETA:Mumbai:05-Jan-2004:55000
1005:Alice:PA:::26-Aug-2014:25000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
1007:Kirsten:PM:IMS:Mumbai:26-Aug-2014:45000
1004:BobGL::ETA:Mumbai:05-Jan-2021:55000         this is the output, giving space even doesn't work, the 5th line shouldn't come.

Comment: Did you try putting a space between -f and 5?

Comment: yes, same output.

Comment: I think this command should work `cut -d ":" -f 5 /tmp/emp.txt | grep "a" `  it will get you all locations which have an 'a' in them. I tested with a file `/tmp/emp.txt` with the data you pasted above.

Comment: Yes, this does give location but we need to print details too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below command should you give you records for location containing 'a'

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; } $5 ~ /a/ ' employee.txt
```